# Как найти и изменить идущие подряд (последовательно) значения, число которых превышает определенный предел (2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть Pandas DataFrame, содержащий единицы и нули.

Пример:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'number':[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]})

   number
0       1
1       0
2       1
3       1
4       1
5       1
6       1
7       1
8       0
9       1
```

Как обнулить значения в тех строках, которые следуют за двумя *идущими подряд (последовательно)* единицами?

Т.е.:

```
   number
0       1
1       0
2       1
3       1
4       1   # (3rd consecutive `1`) --> 0
5       1
6       1
7       1   # (3rd consecutive `1`) --> 0
8       0
9       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
mask = df.groupby(df['number'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1) % 3 == 0
df.loc[mask, 'number'] = 0
```

Результат:

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]:
   number
0       1
1       0
2       1
3       1
4       0
5       1
6       1
7       0
8       0
9       1
```

Пошагово:

```
In [77]: df['number'].diff()
Out[77]:
0    NaN
1   -1.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
8   -1.0
9    1.0
Name: number, dtype: float64

In [78]: df['number'].diff().ne(0)
Out[78]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
9     True
Name: number, dtype: bool

In [79]: df['number'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
Out[79]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
9    5
Name: number, dtype: int32

In [80]: df.groupby(df['number'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount()
Out[80]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    5
8    0
9    0
dtype: int64

In [81]: df.groupby(df['number'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1) % 3
Out[81]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    0
5    1
6    2
7    0
8    1
9    1
dtype: int64
```